# Vaadin build failure after changing in the vaadin version and vaadin plugin version

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

Build failure after I changed the pom.xml file's vaadin version no and vaadin plugin version no

```
<vaadin.version>7.4.5</vaadin.version>
<vaadin.plugin.version>7.4.5</vaadin.plugin.version>
```

then i tried to clean and rebuild the project but build failure shows up that says :

```
 Copying 3 resources

--- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.4.5:resources (default) @ TEST ---
auto discovered modules [com.test.tb.AppWidgetSet]
4 source files from GWT module com.test.tb.AppWidgetSet

<<< vaadin-maven-plugin:7.4.5:compile (default) @ TEST<<<

--- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.4.5:compile (default) @ TEST ---
auto discovered modules [com.test.tb.AppWidgetSet]
Compiling module com.test.bb.AppWidgetSet
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker$CompileDependencyVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:227)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.getCompileDependencySignature(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:209)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.getSignatureHash(CompiledClass.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:42)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:37)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies.resolve(Dependencies.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:366)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:580)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
[INFO] NETBEANS-ExecEvent:{"exc":{"msg":"="},"mojo":{"phase":"prepare-package","loc":{"col":32,"loc":""}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 55.494s
Finished at: Wed May 20 10:25:50 BDT 2015
Final Memory: 39M/203M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.4.5:compile (default) on project GB: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss2048k -classpath "F:\official projects\GB-Core\target\classes;F:\official projects\GB-Core\src\main\java;F:\official projects\GB-Core\src\main\resources;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.30\mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\eclipselink\2.5.1\eclipselink-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\commonj.sdo\2.1.1\commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\reveregroup\gwt\gwt-image-loader\1.1.1\gwt-image-loader-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\addon\jpacontainer\3.2.0\jpacontainer-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-server\7.4.5\vaadin-server-7.4.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-sass-compiler\0.9.12\vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.12.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\flute\flute\1.3.0.gg2\flute-1.3.0.gg2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-shared\7.4.5\vaadin-shared-7.4.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\streamhtmlparser\streamhtmlparser-jsilver\0.0.10.vaadin1\streamhtmlparser-jsilver-0.0.10.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\guava\16.0.1.vaadin1\guava-16.0.1.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.8.1\jsoup-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client-compiled\7.4.5\vaadin-client-compiled-7.4.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client-compiler\7.4.5\vaadin-client-compiler-7.4.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.1\commons-collections-3.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.11\cssparser-0.9.11.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.3\asm-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\5.0.3\asm-util-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\5.0.3\asm-tree-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\5.0.3\asm-commons-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-annotations\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-annotations-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-plus\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-plus-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.transaction\1.1.1.v201105210645\javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-jndi\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-jndi-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-server-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.servlet\3.0.0.v201112011016\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.mail.glassfish\1.4.1.v201005082020\javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.activation\1.1.0.v201105071233\javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-webapp-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-xml\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-xml-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-servlet-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-security-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.annotation\1.1.0.v201108011116\javax.annotation-1.1.0.v201108011116.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\org.objectweb.asm\3.1.0.v200803061910\org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.v200803061910.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlets\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-servlets-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-continuation\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-continuation-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-client\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-client-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-http-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-io-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\8.1.12.v20130726\jetty-util-8.1.12.v20130726.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jdesktop\swing-worker\1.1\swing-worker-1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.8\commons-codec-1.8.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.1\httpclient-4.3.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3\httpcore-4.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3.1\httpmime-4.3.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.19\nekohtml-1.9.19.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\50.1.1\icu4j-50.1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client\7.4.5\vaadin-client-7.4.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-themes\7.4.5\vaadin-themes-7.4.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\javax.persistence\2.1.0\javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\addons\imagestrip\3.0\imagestrip-3.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\11\12\1\12-1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\3.3\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\addon\confirmdialog\2.1.1\confirmdialog-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jsp\jsp-api\2.1\jsp-api-2.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\itextpdf\itextpdf\5.0.6\itextpdf-5.0.6.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcmail-jdk14\1.38\bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk14\1.38\bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bctsp-jdk14\1.38\bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\fop\1.1\fop-1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\xmlgraphics-commons\1.5\xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-svg-dom\1.7\batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-anim\1.7\batik-anim-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-css\1.7\batik-css-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-dom\1.7\batik-dom-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-parser\1.7\batik-parser-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-util\1.7\batik-util-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis-ext\1.3.04\xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-bridge\1.7\batik-bridge-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-script\1.7\batik-script-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-js\1.7\batik-js-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-xml\1.7\batik-xml-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.6.0\xalan-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-awt-util\1.7\batik-awt-util-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-gvt\1.7\batik-gvt-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-transcoder\1.7\batik-transcoder-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-svggen\1.7\batik-svggen-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-extension\1.7\batik-extension-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-ext\1.7\batik-ext-1.7.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\de\steinwedel\vaadin\addon\messagebox\2.0.6\messagebox-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\addons\countdownclock\2.0.1\countdownclock-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\1.5.2\joda-time-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.10-FINAL\poi-3.10-FINAL.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.10-FINAL\poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.10-FINAL\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\openxml4j\1.0-beta\openxml4j-1.0-beta.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.8\log4j-1.2.8.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-scratchpad\3.2-FINAL\poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.5.2\javax.mail-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.9.4\ant-launcher-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\james\apache-mime4j\0.6.1\apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-shared-deps\1.0.3\vaadin-shared-deps-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client-compiler-deps\1.1.0\vaadin-client-compiler-deps-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.8.1\ant-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava-gwt\17.0\guava-gwt-17.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\addons\dcharts-widget\1.7.0\dcharts-widget-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\addons\animator\2.0.0\animator-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\vaadin\addons\dom\0.1.0\dom-0.1.0.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client\7.4.5\vaadin-client-7.4.5.jar;C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\vaadin-client-compiler\7.4.5\vaadin-client-compiler-7.4.5.jar" "-Dgwt.persistentunitcachedir=F:\official projects\test\target\cache" com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war "F:\official projects\test\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\widgetsets" -localWorkers 4 -XfragmentCount -1 -extra "F:\official projects\test\target\extra" -compileReport -deploy "F:\official projects\test\target\temp" -gen "F:\official projects\test\target\.generated" com.test.tb.AppWidgetSet
]] failed with status 1
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

the link of [Help 1] doesn't give any clue what's going wrong. the project running nicely if i go back to the previous version of vaadin 7.3.10

Comment: Have you tryed a clean build, so it wipes all old downloaded/generated objects?

Comment: @AndréSchild yeah I've tried to clean build the project but the build failure keeps coming

Answer (score 2):

See this [forum thread](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9316748) about this exact problem.  The error originates from you having different versions of `org.ow2.asm:asm` in your classpath.  You would have to find the culprit (dependencies in maven) and then put the proper dep *before* the one pulling in the old one. E.g.:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
     <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.3</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```